# Sender ID Not Showing AWS SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS SMS and using the Console to send SMS messages to myself! I tried specifying the `Sender ID` to be my name, but when the SMS is received, it does not display my name is the sender. Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you in India? This might be related: [AWS Developer Forums: Last minute request from Amazon SNS ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=313568)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi! No, I am located in Washington. Does that help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Supported Regions and countries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html), `Sender ID` is no longer supported in the United States.